# How do I take a line from a file into a variable? (PHP)

Tags: php

Ok, I have a file that updates every once in a while by another php file.  This is what it has:

> 137586
>
> HDdeltin
>
> 14/07/1

I want to make a variable for each line, like $admincode for he first line, $name for the second line, and $date for the third line. When I tried having the "137586" as $admincode variable, it took the whole file as its variable. How do I make it so each variable will have the line specified as its value?

Comment: I tried Fget, but it took all of the lines instead of the one I specified. Fget may just work for PHP 4.x, because I had made that mistake a few times.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php, it got all the lines?

Comment: You can use PHP `fgets` and accomplish what you want. You don't have to read line by line. Split the string that `fgets` spits out by `\r\n` or `\n` and check if the line starts with a new line character to exclude empty lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an array of all lines in a file with `file($filename)`
Then you could either use static line numbers to get the single lines or you could use regular expressions.

Sample for getting the lines static:

```
$array = file($myFile);
$admincode = $array[0];
$name = $array[1];
$date = $array[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have many options, you've already got one of them by courtesy of Paedow. If you want to exclude new line characters from those variables and skip empty lines within the file you can use the following code:

```
$file_lines = file($file_path, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES 
                              | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$admincode = $file_lines[0];
$name = $file_lines[1];
$name = $file_lines[2];
```

The manual way of doing this without the option of skipping empty lines would be as follows in the next lines of code.

```
function get_lines_from_file($file_path, $skip_empty_lines=TRUE, 
                             $ignore_new_line_characters=TRUE) {

    $file_string = file_get_contents($file_path);
    $file_lines = explode("\r\n", $file_string);
    $new_line = "\r\n";

    if( count($file_lines)==1 ) {

        $file_lines = explode("\n", $file_string);
        $new_line = "\n";

    }

    $result = array();

    foreach($file_lines as $file_line) {

        if($skip_empty_lines && $file_line!="") {

            $file_line = ($ignore_new_line_characters)
                   ? $file_line : $file_line.$new_line;
            array_push($result, $file_line);

        }
        else if($skip_empty_lines===FALSE) {

            $file_line = ($ignore_new_line_characters) 
                   ? $file_line : $file_line.$new_line;
            array_push($result, $file_line);

        }

    }

    return $result;

}
```